# Accessing TFS Configuration Center after installation

Tags: tfs, self-signed, build-agent

I want to create **Self-signed-certificate** in TFS so that my build agent can connect to TFS (which it can't currently Err. "Basic authentication Requires a secure connection to server"). I have read that in order to create a self signed certificate and host the tfs using HTTPS, "**TFS Configuration Wizard**" creates two **self signed certificates**.  But the problem I cant find TFS Configuration Wizard anywhere I believe it runs while installation is in progress but how can I now access it and create the certificates? 
All help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Application Server feature as the screenshot below, then reconfigure it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't see how it will help me in this case. I want to connect from build machine to TFS server and having the error that "basic authentication requires a secure connection"  I don't see it can help me in this regard.

Comment: You've mentioned in your post "the problem I cant find TFS Configuration Wizard anywhere I believe it runs while installation is in progress but how can I now access it and create the certificates".

Comment: Check this link about how to run the agent with self-signed certificate to see whether it helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/certificate?view=tfs-2018

Comment: yes only if I can access it afterwards then I can create Self signed certificates. for the creation of self signed certificates every thread I have read has referred to the configuration wizard

Comment: What you want is configure application tier, so try to remove this feature and reconfigure it (my screenshot shows), you'll see the configuration wizard.

Comment: thanks for the help but I wont be able to do so due to other project dependencies . I have solved the problem with another workaround

Comment: I ended up changing the authentication type I am no more using PAT